# Unable to pull images from GCR in k8s/minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube, google-container-registry

When my pods start, they fail with `Failed to pull image "gcr.io/myproject/backend:staging": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcr.io/myproject/backend, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

This is happening on `minikube`, despite the fact that (I believe) I have correctly created the service account in GCP, created a Secret based on the downloaded key in the namespace the pods are in, and patched the default service account, i.e.,

```
kubectl --namespace=staging create secret docker-registry gcr-json-key --docker-server=https://gcr.io --docker-username=_json_key --docker-password="$(cat ~/Downloads/gcr-read-key.json)" --docker-email=me@email.com
kubectl --namespace=staging patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "gcr-json-key"}]}'
```

Examining the GCR images web view shows the repo and an image with the specified tags.

I've also tried adding the `imagePullSecrets` entry in the deploy file to no good effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add to your service account a rol to access the storage on GCS, at the end the registry is on top of a bucket